# Title in url instead of tid?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search, uri

How can I display the title in URLs instead of the taxonomy ID?

`www.abc.com/search-page?tid=01` should be `www.abc.com/search-page?title=this-is-the-first-post`.

I am using Taxonomy Terms as Search in Views (Configure filter `criterion: Content: Has taxonomy term`). When I click on taxonomy, I will find more button; when I click i will find "Filter identifier" by default "tid" is present.

When i tried to change that to *title*, it displayed *Page not found*.

On *Views >> Advanced >> Contextual Filters*, I added the field for the title, but even this is not working.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can use Token to replace the tid with node title.

Comment: @Gulok : how to use token, can u plz help  me on this. Thanks !

Comment: you mean taxonomy title or node title?

Comment: @DavidMcsmith, term name.  both will do for me, im doing this for seo friendly

Comment: I am not an SEO expert, but I doubt that this will improve SEO in anyway as filters are not links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have fixed this, just for other guys who are facing the same issue, I thought to post this.

1. created a Taxonomy Page with tag selected
2. save and edit
3. FIELDS -> add your necessary fields
4. FILTER CRITERIA -> add: Taxonomy term: Name (exposed)
5. click on Advance tab to the right side
6. RELATIONSHIPS -> add : Taxonomy term: Content with term
7. CONTEXTUAL FILTERS -> add : Taxonomy term: Name

I'm using exposed form "Exposed form in block:Yes" to be displayed as a block and can be assigned to the page.

[image]

**Search Result in URL : drupal-7/search-new-1?name=tag**

Comment: Can you be more specific on "Create a Taxonomy Page" (step 1.) Do you mean a Views page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by the module - TVI

https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi

Install the module from the above link.

After enable this module, remove the filter criteria just remain the contexual filter with validation criteria of taxonomy id.

Now, go to the taxonomy edit page, there is one checkbox generated by that module, check that and select the view from the dropdown.

Clear all the cache.

This works for me, i hope this helps you.